# Función en ámbito local modificada en ámbito global en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, scope

Bueno, pensaba que tenía claro el tema del ámbito de funciones, cuando me encontré con un caso en el que la variable global era actualizada dentro del ámbito de la función.

```
var fromTo = function fromTo(i,limit){
        return function(){
            var next = i;
            if(i<limit){
                i += 1;
                return next;
            }
            return undefined;
        }
    }
var collect = function collect(fromToFn,array){
        return function (){
            var value = fromToFn();
            if (value !== undefined){
                array.push(value);
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    var array = [];
    var col = collect(fromTo(0,2),array);
    //fromTo dos números incrementados, pues tiene un límite de dos, empezando de 0, o sea devuelve en cada llamada 0, 1 y a la tercera al superar el límite undefined
    //collect devuelve, el valor de FromTo y va añadiendoló a un array, siempre que no sea undefined.
    //Las llamadas
    col() //returns 0
    col() //returns 1
    col() //returns undefined
    array //returns [0,1]
```

¿Por qué el array que ha sido modificado dentro del scope de la función o sea local, ha sido modificado en el global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript pasa los parámetros como ***call-by-sharing***. Esto significa que los objetos (arrays incluídos) son pasados por valor, pero el valor pasado es una referencia a este mismo objeto.

Vayamos a un ejemplo concreto:

```js
var objeto1 = {valor: "original"},
    objeto2 = {valor: "original"};

function modificar (o1, o2){
    o1.valor = "nuevo";
    o2 = {valor: "nuevo"};
}

modificar(objeto1, objeto2);

console.log(objeto1); //{valor: "nuevo"}
console.log(objeto2); //{valor: "original"}
```

Es decir que, al cambiar el valor de una variable, no cambia el valor del objeto primitivo, simplemente apunta la variable a un nuevo objeto.

**Pero**, al cambiar una de sus propiedades (o un índice del array), **cambia al objeto original**.

Es decir, al usar `.push()` para agregar un elemento, se está modificando el array original.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2],
    array2 = [1, 2];

function modificar (a1, a2){
    a1.push(3);
    a2 = [1, 2, 3];
}

modificar(array1, array2);

console.log(array1); //[1, 2, 3];
console.log(array2); //[1, 2];
```